# Just set up my rDNS entry. Want to make sure I've done everything that's required

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, reverse-dns

I've setup one of my domains to point to my Linode IP address:

```
server.mydomain.net > 1.1.1.1
```

I then went into my Linode DNS manager and set the rDNS entry to the above URI. I then set my hostname on the server with the following:

```
cat /etc/hostname
server.mydomain.net

cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost lil00-000 server.mydomain.net
```

Is this all that's required correctly setup my server's hostname? The IP correctly resolves to my server but I want to ensure emails won't get flagged as spam coming from my server due to a badly configured hostname.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/hosts only affects this machine, not any others. You must register your hostnames where you host your domain. For rDNS it is your internet connection provider who can set it up.